# Issue with passing "locale" variable in Apollo useQuery and Strapi v4

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client, strapi, react-apollo

Trying to fetch localized content from Strapi v4 (PostgreSQL) with Apollo GraphQL's useQuery. It works fine when the `locale` value is hardcoded, but not when passing it as variable. [Docs](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/i18n#usage-with-the-graphql-plugin).

**Example #1 (THIS WORKS):**

```
export const GET_CATS = gql`
  query GetCategories {
    categories( locale: "en") {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
        }
      }
    }
}
`;
```

*NOTE: Above works with other locales too, e.g. "de".*

**Example #2 (NOT WORKING):**

```
export const GET_CATS = gql`
  query GetCategories($locale: String) {
    categories( locale: $locale ) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
        }
      }
    }
}

export function useCategories() {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CATS, {
      variables: { locale: 'en' },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    });
  
    return { data, loading, error };
  }
`;
```

Error:

> [ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 400]

**Example #3 (THIS WORKS):**
Here I use `filters:`, and the variable works:

```
export const GET_CATS = gql`   
 query GetCategories($locale: String) {
    categories(filters:{ locale: { eq: $locale }})  {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
        }
      }
    } } `;

export function useCategories() {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CATS, {
      variables: { locale: 'en' },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    });
  
    return { data, loading, error };   }
```

BUT in this case if I use any other variable as locale, e.g. `locale: "de"`, than the query returns an empty array. Possibly because not all categories are translated into "de"? But than why does "de" successfully return translated content in Example #1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to use `I18NLocaleCode!` instead of `String` as variable type:

```
query Categories($id: ID, $locale: I18NLocaleCode!) {
...
}
```